# IE8 corrupting the script src?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a page that includes a dynamic js-script depending on the page I'm visiting. However, I'm getting errors in my log from some IE8-visitors, where it seems like the actual request-url is completely mangled for the mentioned script.

This is what it should fetch:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="?partial=filterjs&json=true&viewall"></script>`

which translates to /sv/5/outlet?partial=filterjs&json=true&viewall

However, looking in my logs, I see stuff like:

```
/sv/5/outlet?partial=filterjs&json=truepor</a></li></ul></h2></li><li%20class=
/sv/7/jackor?partial=filteent/view/teams
```

It seems to truncate the url, and append random stuff from the actual markup that comes later on (way later on, in fact, although approx at the same offset)

I first thought it had something to do with the new XSS-filter that IE8 implemented, but tried disabling it using the HTTP-header

`X-XSS-Protection: 0`

Without success.

I cannot reproduce this error on my own machine either, however this happens several times a day (on a site with approx 3000 visits per day). This is happening on both XP, Vista and Win7 according to the user-agent (NT 5.1, 6.0 and 6.1).

Anyone recognize this behaviour?

Comment: I'd start by fixing the errors that http://validator.w3.org/ will throw up.

Comment: @David: What makes you think his pages aren't valid? He hasn't quoted anything to suggest that (I'm assuming the line break after the `?` in his first example was for our benefit, not actually there.)

Comment: And keep pulling large swaths out of the page until you pinpoint which one is invalid or not well formed, or just cause a problem in general.

Comment: @T.J. Because I can see `&` characters in the snippits that have been posted that aren't represented as `&amp;`. What makes you think that isn't his actual code? He doesn't say that.

Comment: @David: I think I'm making a reasonable assumption about the line break. You're right about the `&amp;` s (missed that!), though I'm sure we both know they have nothing to do with *this* problem. You're right nearly every time you point people at validation (which you do regularly, and again, rightly), it just came off a bit OT and sarky to me this time 'round.

Comment: While that particular issue with validation probably isn't the cause (which is why I commented instead of answering), it does indicate that the author hasn't taken care to make sure the document is valid. this means there is a good chance that it has other issues which might be causing the problem. Validation is a cheap way to avoid many issues and is always worth doing before you start asking other people to help.

Comment: @David: Completely agree that it's a cheap way to avoid issues and should be done a *lot* more than it is.

Comment: I see your points, and validation is a good thing. I have been studying the markup and will inform the person in charge that he should look over it, however my believe was that this was more deeply rooted (which I got confirmed from the answer below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a [known bug](http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/27/Bugs-in-the-IE8-Lookahead-Downloader.aspx) in the lookahead downloader in Internet Explorer, where it drops a 4k part of the page when doing lookahead downloads.

This sometimes means that an URL for a resource in the page is cut and combined with some other text later in the page, resulting in a bad URL being requested.

The lookahead downloader is only used to try to fill the cache beforehand, when the resource is actually needed in the page it will be requested with the correct URL, so the user doesn't experience any errors in the page because of this.

Comment: Ah, this sounds very reasonable since when looking into the source and checking the amount of code that is actually dropped it is in 80% of the cases exactly 4119 bytes (in UTF-8), or 3890 chars. I'm guessing my cut and pasting between programs modifies the length a bit, therefor it isn't exactly 4096 bytes. Great answer! I will safely assume that this doesn't bother users.